# How to write data from csv file to MySQL database with python?

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to write data from csv file to MySQL database with python. I created a table in MySQL with the query:

```
CREATE TABLE books_table(rating VARCHAR(20), product_type VARCHAR(20), upc VARCHAR(20), title VARCHAR(20));
```

Below is the python code for writing data:

```
import os
import csv
import glob
import pymysql
 
 
 
csv_filepath = r"D:\Scraping projects\items.csv"
 
mydb = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', user='root', passwd='password', db='books_db')
cursor = mydb.cursor()
 
with open(csv_filepath, "r") as csv_file:
 
    csv_data =csv.reader(csv_file)
    row_count = 0
 
    for row in csv_data:    
        print(row)
        if row_count != 0:
            try:
                cursor.execute('INSERT IGNORE INTO books_table(rating, product_type, upc, title) VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s)', row)
                row_count += 1
            except Exception:
                pass
 
mydb.commit()
cursor.close()
```

The code did not show any error in the terminal and when I check the MySQL Database, it is empty. You can also check the content of csv file below which comes from print command:

```
['title', 'rating', 'upc', 'product_type']
["It's Only the Himalayas", 'Two', 'a22124811bfa8350', 'Books']
['Olio', 'One', 'feb7cc7701ecf901', 'Books']
['Our Band Could Be Your Life: Scenes from the American Indie Underground, 1981-1991', 'Three', 'deda3e61b9514b83', 'Books']
["Scott Pilgrim's Precious Little Life (Scott Pilgrim #1)", 'Five', '3b1c02bac2a429e6', 'Books']
['Libertarianism for Beginners', 'Two', 'a18a4f574854aced', 'Books']
['Rip it Up and Start Again', 'Five', 'a34ba96d4081e6a4', 'Books']
['Set Me Free', 'Five', 'ce6396b0f23f6ecc', 'Books']
['Mesaerion: The Best Science Fiction Stories 1800-1849', 'One', 'e30f54cea9b38190', 'Books']
['Starving Hearts (Triangular Trade Trilogy, #1)', 'Two', '0312262ecafa5a40', 'Books']
['The Black Maria', 'One', '1dfe412b8ac00530', 'Books']
['The Boys in the Boat: Nine Americans and Their Epic Quest for Gold at the 1936 Berlin Olympics', 'Four', 'e10e1e165dc8be4a', 'Books']
['The Dirty Little Secrets of Getting Your Dream Job', 'Four', '2597b5a345f45e1b', 'Books']
['The Requiem Red', 'One', 'f77dbf2323deb740', 'Books']
['Sapiens: A Brief History of Humankind', 'Five', '4165285e1663650f', 'Books']
['Sharp Objects', 'Four', 'e00eb4fd7b871a48', 'Books']
['Soumission', 'One', '6957f44c3847a760', 'Books']
['The Coming Woman: A Novel Based on the Life of the Infamous Feminist, Victoria Woodhull', 'Three', 'e72a5dfc7e9267b2', 'Books']
['Tipping the Velvet', 'One', '90fa61229261140a', 'Books']
['A Light in the Attic', 'Three', 'a897fe39b1053632', 'Books']
["Shakespeare's Sonnets", 'Four', '30a7f60cd76ca58c', 'Books']
```

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: You are not saving anything in DB because you have _if row_count != 0:_ and when you get in the loop row_count allways is 0. You need to put **row_count += 1** outside the if

Comment: Indeed, my mistake on indentation. Thanks, mate

Comment: @Ken Masters  It is not an indentation issue, it is a logic error.  the code row_count += 1 never executes because the if row_count != 0: statement never lets it get there....so row_count is forever 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@nano deserves the credit, he's the first one to see the error.
You can fix your code like so:

```
 import os
 import csv
 import glob
 import pymysql
 
 csv_filepath = r"D:\Scraping projects\items.csv"
 
 mydb = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', user='root', passwd='password', db='books_db')
 cursor = mydb.cursor()
 
 with open(csv_filepath, "r") as csv_file:
 
      csv_data =csv.reader(csv_file)
      row_count = 0

      for row in csv_data:    
           print(row)
           if row_count != 0:
           try:
                cursor.execute('INSERT IGNORE INTO books_table(title, rating, upc, product_type) VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s)', row)
           except Exception:
                pass
           row_count += 1

 mydb.commit()
 cursor.close()
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try to commit inside context manager(with):

```
with open(csv_filepath, "r") as csv_file:
 
    csv_data =csv.reader(csv_file)
    row_count = 0
 
    for row in csv_data:    
        print(row)
        if row_count != 0:
            try:
                cursor.execute('INSERT IGNORE INTO books_table(rating, product_type, upc, title) VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s)', row)
                row_count += 1
            except Exception:
                pass
    mydb.commit()

 

cursor.close()
```

Comment: This code suffers from the same issue that the OP's code does

Answer (score -1):

Maybe the field: rating varchar(20) the length too short,  Please change to: rating VARCHAR(200)

```
CREATE TABLE books_table(rating VARCHAR(200), product_type VARCHAR(20), upc VARCHAR(20), title VARCHAR(20));
```